# Relative URL Paths for images

Tags: html, url, web, web-crawler

Working on a project which involves crawling some legislation sites and hit a puzzler
This url https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/F2018L00530
has a base setting of https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/F2018L00530/Html/Text
in its header but images on the page resolve relative to https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/F2018L00530/Html/ and I cannot determine why.  Its not a frame and I cannot see something else which would change the path.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently if you use the base tag, the browser ignores everything after the last slash. So a base of https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/F2018L00530/Html/Text 
is equivalent to https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/F2018L00530/Html/
which corresponds to what we are seeing.

Weird, but I tried it with a test page with similar results.